# Too much binding in javascript with prototypes and callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, prototype

So i'm writing a console game in node. It's a simple game where it accepts some user input in the console to play. There is no ui. I am testing my knowledge of object oriented programming so I have created a game constructor and the specific game constructor (say checkers for example). The big issue i'm having is that I need to call functions in a certain succession as you typically do in node with callbacks. In my prototypes I have to keep binding this to like every function call so that I can access the correct methods and keep track of the fields that have been defined. Is this the wrong way to go about this? It seems like this is making things overly complicated. I can post some example code if need be but I'm just curious about the general architecture of this type of code.

Another question I have is when I have a prototype that takes an inupt, if that input is available on the object through the this context, should I use this.field for the parameter or call the function passing in that parameter?

Comment: If you're frequently doing `.bind(this)`, you may well want the lexical scoping that comes with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: An extremely common paradigm is to capture `this` in a variable outside the callback that can be used inside the callback such as `var self = this` and then inside the callback use `self` in place of `this`. You can also `.bind` and not feel bad about it.

Comment: @lonesomeday arrow functions are only available in ES6 correct? I am restricted to ES5 for this problem. Though could I use something like babel to compile it into ES5?

Comment: @Adam I was thinking about doing that since it made the most sense. I didn't know if that was an antipattern or not. I am going to be graded not really on the functionality of the code (as that should work 100%) but on the design of the code.

Comment: @layonthebeech Correct, yes.

Comment: Relevant `jsperf` test: https://jsperf.com/bind-vs-self-closure/24

Comment: @layonthebeech Though you're targeting Node, so you can in theory be a little freer with your use of modern syntax!

Comment: There are many kinds of callbacks. Which are you using? Obviously there's asynchronous input/output (even if just on the console), but other than that callbacks should be largely unnecessary. Maybe try passing your object instances around so that methods can be invoked on them, instead of passing bound methods around to be called? Yes, show us your code.

Comment: @layonthebeech If you're only building this app for test purposes, and not planning on shipping anything in production, you could use babel-node. babel-node ships with babel-cli and is meant for testing purposes only (as it has significant performance and startup time costs). You can see an example babel-node application here: https://github.com/babel/example-node-server

Comment: @layonthebeech Further, if you do use babel-node you could use the bind operator (`::`) and bind callbacks to this, e.g., `this::function (arg) { ... }`. More information on the bind operator is available in the tc39 proposal https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator